# Redux / React Native State gets values from previous states and does not update/re-render correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state, native

There is so many weird things going on here that I don't know where to start. Most funny thing is that it used to work just fine and suddenly stopped.

This is the flow:

1. `screens/Add.js` => I create a post object in the State, pass it to my PostAPI => firebase => add to redux store => show in the FeedScreen.
2. Redirect to `screens/feed.js`. The post appears after a few seconds. Till now everything goes all right.
3. If I like the post, it increments the `post.likes.total` by one. I look it up by ID in the redux store and update the array => new state rerenders the post list which receives the posts through mapState ToProps. The changes appear as expected.
4. Now I create a new post... it goes same as above.
5. The **new post gets the same number of likes as the previous** i just clicked! And all the future posts get the same amount of previous likes and are ALSO UPDATED when I click on THE PREVIOUSLY created posts. When clicking on the just created one, it updates only itself. Clicking on the previous, it updates itself and the following. Clicking on the 3rd post will update itself and the 2 following and so on.
6. If I reload the page, likes are correctly loaded from the DB, but the post created with likes from the previous post will in fact be created with those likes in the DB.

The problem before was that I forgot to put a Key property on the child component and therefore it didn't want to update, and doing slice() on the array did the trick as well.

But now whats going on??? **How is even the `this.state.post` in `AddScreen` aware of likes of the last liked post?** It is not dependent on anything, it is a completely separate screen with no link to redux state or any other props. And it happens only to likes. Description, pictures and comments show up correctly.

Please help me cause I'm loosing my mind, i've spent so many days on it and it came back like a nightmare after working fine for a week. I've tried so many things (giving key props everywhere, different returns of redux state, different approaches of rendering in Component and useEffect...). I hope you come with a rescue!

Some pictures:

[1st post appears in the feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9E3d.png)

[post gets 3 likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Mal.png)

[create 2nd post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNM00.png)

[Second posts is created with the same amount of likes as the previous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpgZ2.png)

[I liked the 1st post 2 times and the last post 2 times, so the last post gets 3+2+2 likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjLU.png)

Here is the code, I removed some unimportant lines for the sake of readability. You can see the full code here: https://github.com/ginold/instagramCloneReactNative

**Add Post Screen**

```
    export class AddScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          post: {
            author: '', createdAt: null, description: '',
            location: {}, likes: { total: 0 }, comments: [],
            pictures: []
          }
        }
        this.defaultPost = this.state.post
        this._addPost = this._addPost.bind(this)
      }
      _addPost() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { uploading: true })
        PostApiService.addPost(this.state.post)
        this.setState({ post: this.defaultPost })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.post)) // even here the newly created post will have post.likes same as previous one!
      }

      render() {
        const { pictures } = this.state.post;

        return (

          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView
              contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
              <Button>Next</Button>

              <Layout>
                <Text>Add a caption</Text>
                <Input
                  multiline={true}
                  numberOfLines={4}
                  iconResult={<Icon name='home-outline' size={25} />}
                  placeholder={'write something...'}
                  onChangeText={(text) => {
                    const post = this.state.post
                    this.setState({ post: { ...post, description: text } })
                  }}
                  value={this.state.post.description}>
                </Input>
              </Layout>
              <Button onPress={this._addPost}>SHARE</Button>
            </ScrollView>
          </SafeAreaView >
        );
      }
    };
```

**Post Reducer**

```
    if (action.type === "ADD_LIKE") {
      const postId = action.payload
      let posts = state.allPosts
      posts.map(post => {
        if (post.id === postId) {
          return { ...post, likes: { total: post.likes.total += 1 } }
        }
        return post
      })
      return { ...state, allPosts: posts.slice() } // quick fix for props not re-rendering in the feed
    }
    if (action.type === "SET_POSTS") {

      return { ...state, allPosts: action.payload }
    }
    if (action.type === "ADD_POST") {
      const post = action.payload // post object
      const posts = state.allPosts
      return { ...state, allPosts: [post, ...state.allPosts] }
    }
    return state
```

**Post Actions = where likes are, child of Post Component**

```
    class PostActions extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { post: this.props.post }
        this.size = 32
        this.addLike = this.addLike.bind(this)
      }
      addLike() {
        PostService.addLike(this.props.post)
        PostsReduxService.addLike(this.state.post.id)
      };
      render() {
        const { post } = this.state
        return (
            <Layout style={styles.heartIcon} key={`${ post.id } -heart`}>
              <Text key={`${ post.id } -likes`}>{`${ post.likes.total } likes`}  </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addLike}>
                <Icon name={post.likes.total > 0 ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'} width={this.size} height={this.size} fill='red' />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Layout>
          </Layout>
        )
      }
    }
```

**Post List with Post components, connected to mapStateToProps**

```
    const PostList = (props) => {
        const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([])

        React.useEffect(() => {
            if (props.posts.length === 0) {
                PostApiService.getPosts().then((posts) => {
                    PostsReduxService.setPosts(posts)
                    setPosts(posts)
                })
            }
            if (posts.length !== props.posts.length) {
                setPosts(props.posts)
            }
        }, [props.posts])


        const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
            <Layout style={styles.listItem} key={`${ item.id } -list - item`}>
                {/* causes an error in the console, it's a known bug in ui-kitten */}
                <Post key={`${ item.id }-post`} item={item} />
            </Layout>
        );
        return (
            (posts && !!posts.length && !refreshing)
                ? <List >}
                    style={styles.list} data={posts} renderItem={renderItem} />
                : <ActivityIndicator style={styles.loading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />

        )
```

[create 1st post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyl5p.png)

Answer (score 0):

So a few things here:

1. In `Post`, why do you just copy the item into state, you can simply use the post passed from props. So the whole state, useEffect logic can be discarded. That might clear things up.
2. This will also travel down `PostActions`, and the correct like number should be shown.
3. In `PostActions`, you working with both the copy of the post and the post from props, but since you never update the state, you will only update the first one pass to it: `this.state = { post: this.props.post }` but `PostService.addLike(this.props.post)` and here state again `PostsReduxService.addLike(this.state.post.id)`. Again, remove the saving of the post from state and just work the item from props.

Also look into mapDispatchToProps of redux instead of your `PostsReduxService`.

So all in all, you work with multiple sources of thruth.
You save the post in your local component state, but also save them to redux. You should decide on one location where to save it and stick with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In fact deleting the useEffect logic and working with only props gives the same effect so at least the code is a few lines cleaner.
as for PostReduxService : this is where i call myStore.dispatch(action) so technically it is the same as mapDispatchToProps, or is it? I'm pretty sure I have only one source of truth but I will investigate.